# How to slide a mesh into another

Tags: modeling

[image]
Hi everyone. I'm trying to make a groove inside a sphere shape. I would like to enter the tiny circular faces inside the sphere. I tried to extrude but the axe doesnt correspond. I mean the axes I tried are not orthogonal to the faces. Thanks

Comment: I found this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9Tteap4HBc

Comment: So... did the video answer your question?